# How to start a service without open the activity (open the app on boot/or in any other way)

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Is it possible to start a service without open the app or without launching the app. Explaining the scenario

1. User Download and install the app.
2. User do not open the app. Even not a single time after the installation.

Now I want to start a service in above scenario, maybe on reboot of device or any other way.

Is it possible? Many blogs and posts say that it's not possible.

Comment: It will be possible by Broadcast receiver for BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: @jankigadhiya: Not since Android 3.1.

Comment: You mean ??we cannot receive boot complete event of System ?? @CommonsWare

Comment: BOOT_COMPLETED Requires activity to be launched Once at least. Without opening the app it will not work.

Comment: @jankigadhiya: Alpesh is correct. Until the app is moved out of the so-called "stopped state", it will not respond to system broadcasts.

Comment: BOOT_COMPLETED only work if app is opened at least one time after installation.

Comment: It does not need to start the service. You just have to register the broadcast receiver and you will be in `onReceive()` as soon as the booting completes..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya no you will not be in the `onReceive()` because the broadcast will not be received

Comment: @Tim Castelijns I do agree with you. @ janki gadhiya Have you tried and it is working for you. If yes pls do share the code as for us its not working.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible

Not since Android 3.1, to help prevent "drive-by" malware installations.

Comment: Pls guide me how to do it .

Comment: @Alpesh: It is not possible.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your response. Can it be performed while manufacturing of the device by manufacturer. Basically they run a installer app which install other third apps on the device. Like now a days most of the device contains whats app. SO is it possible in that way.?

Comment: @Alpesh: Anyone who builds the ROM (device manufacturers, custom ROM developers, etc.) have some means of setting up their apps to avoid this problem. I do not know the details.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.Lets see if any of us know some specific details about this Like how it can be done or any manufacturing unit which do the same.